# Can we burninate the "paradox" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[paradox](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paradox) doesn't help characterize the physics content of a question. Sure, there are some questions that deal with (apparent) paradoxes, but I think it's enough that the question title or body mentions the paradox in question; there's no real need to make a tag out of it as well.

Does anyone else see a good use for this tag and would care to argue for keeping it? Or should we get rid of it?

Comment: Agreed. Right now [paradox] seems to mean *"I'm lost on something basic"*.

Comment: Agree as well. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill it with fire. Definitely.

Comment: Since there are only a few questions with the tag I've been removing it from them a few at a time. The opinion of mods is that it's not worth getting the devs involved for such a small tag. Let's just say that any time you see a [tag:paradox] tag in the future, just edit it out. (If it becomes a problem, I think we can have it blacklisted)