# Merge the "planet" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, burninate-request

While editing [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144887/planetary-motion), I noticed that we have a tag for [planet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet) as well as one for [planets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets). A slightly deeper than superficial look indicates that [planet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet) is apparently [a synonym](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/planets/synonyms) of [planets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets)--it appears it was used once and then later linked to [planets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets).

Since it seems completely unnecessary, can we merge the [planet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet) tag?

Comment: Burninate, or subsume?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4677/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Done.

In the future just raise such non-controversial merge requests<sup>1</sup> in chat (as opposed to meta), and a moderator will take action.

Note that synonyms are reversible while merges are irreversible (=hard to unshuffle). This is why we often hesitate to perform merges.

--

<sup>1</sup> I changed OP's original wording *burninate request* into *merge request,* because that is technically the relevant term for the [planet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet) tag. More generally, a (typically non-existent) tag name is burninated to prevent its potential future creation if the Phys.SE community decides so. See e.g. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5446/2451) and [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993/2451) meta posts. In contrast to a merge request, a burninate request requires intervention from the SE team outside Phys.SE to be implemented.

Comment: I guess I figured all burninate requests should be done in meta, but duly noted. Thanks!

Comment: It's just not as fun without the fire-breathing dragon in the answer...

Comment: @tpg2114: I added a footnote.

Comment: Ah, okay. I still like that dragon though!